# Is there a reset_index for columns, or a way to move column headers to an inner index leaving their index positions as the outer index?

Tags: python, pandas

Sample DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Is there a way to reset index for columns? or to easily insert a row with column index position values? I'd prefer the index positions to be the outer most index and be left with the column headers as the inner most index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) or `range`:

```
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
#alternatively
#df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
print (df)
   0  1  2  3
0  9  4  0  1
1  9  0  1  8
2  9  0  8  6
3  4  3  0  4
4  6  8  1  8
5  4  1  3  6
6  5  3  9  6
7  9  1  9  4
8  2  6  7  8
9  8  9  2  0
```

But lost column values.

If need [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html) without names:

```
df.columns = [np.arange(len(df.columns)), df.columns]
print (df)
   0  1  2  3
   A  B  C  D
0  9  4  0  1
1  9  0  1  8
2  9  0  8  6
3  4  3  0  4
4  6  8  1  8
5  4  1  3  6
6  5  3  9  6
7  9  1  9  4
8  2  6  7  8
9  8  9  2  0
```

and for names use [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
names = ['a','b']
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.arange(len(df.columns)), df.columns], names=names)
print (df)
a  0  1  2  3
b  A  B  C  D
0  9  4  0  1
1  9  0  1  8
2  9  0  8  6
3  4  3  0  4
4  6  8  1  8
5  4  1  3  6
6  5  3  9  6
7  9  1  9  4
8  2  6  7  8
9  8  9  2  0
```

Comment: any idea how I can get around the fact that I'm hitting key errors when trying to set_index('Inventory Number')? I probably need to review how to set index when using multi-index but figured id ask.

Comment: Maybe some whitespace in column names, check it by print df.columns.tolist() and remove by df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()

Answer (score 11):

**a.1) Drop column names**

```py
df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(df.columns.size)
df
```

Output:

```py
    0   1   2   3
#---------------#
0   0   1   3   3
1   2   2   0   2
2   2   1   3   1
3   2   1   0   0
```

**a.2) Drop column names (one-liner)**
Could have performance issues and side effects, see discussion below.

```py
df.T.reset_index(drop=True).T
```

Output:

```py
    0   1   2   3
#---------------#
0   0   1   3   3
1   2   2   0   2
2   2   1   3   1
3   2   1   0   0
```

**b.1) Move column names into a row (one-liner)**
Same issues, see discussion below.

```py
df.T.reset_index().T
```

Output:

```py
        0   1   2   3
#-------------------#
index   A   B   C   D
   0    0   1   3   3
   1    2   2   0   2
   2    2   1   3   1
   3    2   1   0   0
```

**b.2) Move column names into a row**
Effective way.

```py
 #heterogeneous DataFrame creation
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,4,size=(4, 3)), columns=list('789')).join(
     pd.DataFrame(list('bcde'),columns=['A']))
df.index.name = '4'

#save column as row then reindex column names
df = df.append(pd.Series( df.columns,name = df.index.name,index= df.columns ), )
df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(df.columns.size)
print (df)
print(df.info())
```

Output:  **NB** *you will need extra effort to prevent upcasing of all data*

```py
   0  1  2  3
#-----------#
4            
0  2  3  2  b
1  1  0  2  c
2  3  1  3  d
3  3  3  2  e
4  7  8  9  A

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 4 columns):
0    5 non-null object
1    5 non-null object
2    5 non-null object
3    5 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
```

**c) Add secondary column index (one-liner)**
Could have performance issues and side effects, see discussion below.

```py
df.T.set_index(pd.RangeIndex(df.columns.size),append=True).T
```

Output:

```py
    A   B   C   D
    0   1   2   3
#---------------#
0   0   1   3   3
1   2   2   0   2
2   2   1   3   1
3   2   1   0   0
```

---

### One line approach criticism

**Performance issues**:
For huge datasets could be unacceptable costs of double `T` , but on simple cases one line that returns copy of DataFrame maybe useful. See test results

```py
In [294]: for i in range (3,7):
     ...:     df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,size=(10**i, 10**3)))
     ...:     print ('shape:',df.shape)
     ...:     %timeit df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
     ...: 
shape: (1000, 1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.2 ms per loop
shape: (10000, 1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.3 ms per loop
shape: (100000, 1000)
1 loop, best of 3: 546 ms per loop
shape: (1000000, 1000)
1 loop, best of 3: 9.9 s per loop

In [295]: %timeit df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(df.columns.size)
The slowest run took 28.60 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.74 µs per loop
```

**Side effect (upcasting)**:
Heterogeneous DataFrames will be up-casted

```py
In [352]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,4,size=(4, 3)), columns=list('789')).join(
     ...:          pd.DataFrame(list('bcde'),columns=['A']))

In [353]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 4 columns):
7    4 non-null int64
8    4 non-null int64
9    4 non-null int64
A    4 non-null object
dtypes: int64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 208.0+ bytes
```

.T.T upcasting

```py
In [354]: df.T.T.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 4 columns):
7    4 non-null object
8    4 non-null object
9    4 non-null object
A    4 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 208.0+ bytes
```

---

Comment: It should be slow, because double transpose, what do you think?

Comment: In most cases it is fast enough. By the way im not sure that pandas do anything with data to perform T. I'll check.

Comment: Thanks, try test `1k-rows x 1k-columns`.

Comment: DataFrames store heterogenous data by grouping together different dtypes. When you take the transpose, pandas has to upcast the dtype for rows. This causes unwanted side effects because if your original df has a column of strings and other numeric columns, transpose of its transpose will have all object dtypes. You will not be able to do numeric operations before manually converting them to number again.

Comment: b.2) does move the column names at the end, but it would be better if column names would be at the beginning (first row).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a workaround for it. How I resolved it is, I saved the required df in csv format and then read it again with `headers=None`.

```
# saving your df in csv file
df.to_csv("df1.csv", index=False)
# read the saved df
df = pd.read_csv("df1.csv", header=None, dtype=object)
```

went from

[image: this(Before)]

to

[image: this(After)]

---

**Note:** Since I had small files, it worked for me, but if you have big datasets, this approach is not a good idea.